# jQuery click event not correct after second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been playing around with this all evening, but can't seem to figure out whats wrong with my code.

http://jsfiddle.net/486egfut/

When you click the `menu` button, the navigation will show up, animated with CSS. When you click it again, it disappears. Also CSS animated.

But if you click it a third time, the class `collapsed` gets added, and immediately removed again.

What is the correct way of doing this. Animating the height of an element with CSS, and toggling the `display` after the animation with jQuery?

I've also tried multiple `.on()` events, but unsuccesfull (see below)

```
    $('body').on('click', '.icon-mobile-menu', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).addClass('menu-open');
      $nav.addClass('collapsed').height(312);

    }).on('click', '.menu-open', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).removeClass('menu-open');
      $nav.css('height', '').on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd', function(){
        $nav.removeClass('collapsed');
      });

    });
```

Thanks.

Comment: instead of adding the `menu-open` then removing it u can use `toggleClass` ,also instead of passing empty string to `css('height', '')` use `0` ,and if ur final result is just slide up and down ,u can use `slideUp` and `slideDown` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the handler of the transition effect you are binding triggers EVERYTIME when there is a height change, which includes when you try to collapse the dialog.

Here is a working fix, although it is a bit dirty:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $nav = $('.navigation'),
        $header = $('.header');

    $('.icon-mobile-menu').on('click', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('menu-open');

        if ($nav.hasClass('collapsed')) {
            $nav.css('height', '').on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd', function () {

                // Fix goes here
                if ($nav.height() == 0){
                  $(this).removeClass('collapsed');
                }
            });
        } else {
            $nav.addClass('collapsed').height(75); // fixed height is for demo purposes only.
        }
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/486egfut/12/

Note: Why your first click is working is because you only bind that transition handler on your first click.

Answer (score 0):

u can try

```js
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.icon-mobile-menu').on('click', function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('menu-open');
            $('.navigation').toggleClass('nav-slide');
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.icon-mobile-menu {
    background: red;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.menu-open {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}
.navigation {
    margin-top: 4px;
    background: green;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -moz-transition:all 0.35s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
    -o-transition: all 0.35s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.35s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
    transition: all 0.35s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
}
.nav-slide{
    height: 75px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header"> 
    <span class="icon-mobile-menu">menu</span>
</header>
<div class="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li>Item one</li>
        <li>Item two</li>
        <li>Item three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```